# Java Spark RDD exception. token("*") > ? AND token("*") <= ? ALLOW FILTERING: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT [FROM]...)

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I got a pretty simple example of the Java + Spark + Cassandra java example which I copied from http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=zua6upabiylzeetp&number=2

So, here is the code of my application:

```
package com.chatSparkConnactionTest;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;


public class JavaDemoRDDBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().
            setAppName("chat").
            setMaster("local").
            set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<String> rddBeans = javaFunctions(sc)
            .cassandraTable("chat", "dictionary", mapRowTo(Dictionary.class))
            .map(
            new Function<Dictionary, String>() {
                    public String call(Dictionary dictionary) throws Exception {
                    String row = dictionary.toString();
                    System.out.println("Row :" + row);
                    return row;
                }
        });
        System.out.println(rddBeans.collect().get(0));
        System.out.println(rddBeans.collect().size());
    } 
}
```

Here is the Dictionary class code:

```
package com.chatSparkConnactionTest;

import org.spark_project.guava.base.Objects;

public class Dictionary {
    private String value_id;
    private String d_name;
    private String d_value;

    public static Dictionary newInstance(String value_id, String d_name, String d_value) {
        Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();
        dictionary.setId(value_id);
        dictionary.setName(d_name);
        dictionary.setValue(d_value);
        return dictionary;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return value_id;
    }

    public void setId(String value_id) {
        this.value_id = value_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return d_name;
    }

    public void setName(String d_name) {
        this.d_name = d_name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return d_value;
    }

    public void setValue(String d_value) {
        this.d_value = d_value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Objects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("value_id", value_id)
                .add("d_name", d_name)
                .add("d_value", d_value)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

and this is a code to create Cassandra DB Table:

```
CREATE TABLE dictionary (
  value_id    text,
  d_value     text, 
  d_name    text,
  PRIMARY KEY (value_id, d_name)
) WITH comment = 'dictionary values'
AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (d_name ASC);
INSERT INTO chat.dictionary (d_name,d_value,value_id) VALUES ('Friendship Status','Requested','1');
INSERT INTO chat.dictionary (d_name,d_value,value_id) VALUES ('Friendship Status','Friends','2');
```

I got an error on attempt to run my application (I found two links on this problem, but I can't catch - how to make my application work):
[InvalidRequestException(why:empid cannot be restricted by more than one relation if it includes an Equal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036143/invalidrequestexceptionwhyempid-cannot-be-restricted-by-more-than-one-relation)
[Spark Datastax Java API Select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001566/spark-datastax-java-api-select-statements)

Here is my error:

```
java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT  FROM "chat"."dictionary" WHERE token("value_id") > ? AND token("value_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:293)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:113)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.PreparedStatementCache$.prepareStatement(PreparedStatementCache.scala:45)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:28)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:279)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:132)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:224)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:200)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:861)
    ... 3 more
16/10/09 21:36:06 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, partition 1, ANY, 19449 bytes)
16/10/09 21:36:06 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT  FROM "chat"."dictionary" WHERE token("value_id") > ? AND token("value_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:293)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:113)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.PreparedStatementCache$.prepareStatement(PreparedStatementCache.scala:45)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:28)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:279)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:132)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:224)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:200)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:861)
    ... 3 more

16/10/09 21:36:06 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
16/10/09 21:36:06 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/10/09 21:36:06 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
16/10/09 21:36:06 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
16/10/09 21:36:06 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
16/10/09 21:36:06 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at JavaDemoRDDBean.java:32) failed in 0.163 s
16/10/09 21:36:06 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collect at JavaDemoRDDBean.java:32, took 0.349047 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT  FROM "chat"."dictionary" WHERE token("value_id") > ? AND token("value_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:293)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:113)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.PreparedStatementCache$.prepareStatement(PreparedStatementCache.scala:45)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:28)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:279)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:132)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:224)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:200)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:861)
    ... 3 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:892)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at com.chatSparkConnactionTest.JavaDemoRDDBean.main(JavaDemoRDDBean.java:32)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT  FROM "chat"."dictionary" WHERE token("value_id") > ? AND token("value_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:293)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:113)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.PreparedStatementCache$.prepareStatement(PreparedStatementCache.scala:45)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:28)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:279)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:132)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:224)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:200)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:861)
    ... 3 more
16/10/09 21:36:06 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT  FROM "chat"."dictionary" WHERE token("value_id") > ? AND token("value_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:293)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:307)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$19.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:113)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.PreparedStatementCache$.prepareStatement(PreparedStatementCache.scala:45)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:28)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:279)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'FROM' (SELECT  [FROM]...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:132)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:224)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:200)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:861)
    ... 3 more
```

Can anybody help me to make my simple example workable?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue with your Dictionary javabean class. Use below class.

```
public class Dictionary {
private String value_id;
private String d_name;
private String d_value;

public String getValue_id() {
    return value_id;
}
public void setValue_id(String value_id) {
    this.value_id = value_id;
}
public String getD_name() {
    return d_name;
}
public void setD_name(String d_name) {
    this.d_name = d_name;
}
public String getD_value() {
    return d_value;
}
public void setD_value(String d_value) {
    this.d_value = d_value;
   }
}
```